# How to model roof shape?

Tags: mesh, edges

I'm trying to create something like the attached sketch of a roof. The lines marked in pink would be raised. I've managed to do it, but generally my meshes are really complex, way more than I feel they should be. I think part of the issue is my loops after adding a Subsurf, which go all over the place.

Out of interest, what would be the right way to go about this? Appreciate the help

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: What is it supposed to be?

Comment: Hello, maybe show one of your real objects?

Comment: Is this just supposed to be a roof shape, or is it symmetrical front to back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say your problem is a very complex mesh, and yet you already solved the minimal topology for your problem, which you embedded in your question. Just model it - below on gifs:

1. A default plane, <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> Top Ortographic Mode, <kbd>E</kbd> Extruding, holding <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd> to snap to grid.
2. <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> Add Loopcuts (right-click to cancel sliding it) to create an inner grid where needed (use mouse wheel to change number of cuts), and <kbd>K</kbd> Knife tool to make diagonal cuts.
3. Select unnecessary edges and <kbd>X</kbd> *Dissolve Edges*.

[image] [image] [image]

What's left is selecting the horizontal edges that are supposed to be elevated, and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> moving them up:

[image]

Those triangles on ends of the roofs probably should be vertical - can be fixed by just moving their top vertices, but for such case the workflow becomes even simpler:

[image]

This time I used an alternate method for diagonal edges - <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> sliding vertices. Without *Auto Merge* enabled, I had to <kbd>A</kbd> Select all, and <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Merge By Distance.

Comment: And you may want to extrude everything or add a solidify modifier to give it thickness.

Comment: Markus — thank you for this — it's a massive help. I think I was over thinking it all and ended up with an obscene amount of vertices... I've just tried your method on a few other letters and it's all worked a lot smoother. Thanks so much for taking the time here.

I'm still trying to figure out this stuff, for the most part I get something like I intend, but generally through bodging it badly. I really appreciate you helping me find the right ways!